# Create a relationship between two classes with different property names

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

Using EF 6 and given the following classes:

```
public class A: 
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }

    public string PropA {get; set;}
    public string PorpB {get; set;} 

    public List<B> Bs {get; set;}
}

public class B: 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string PropB {get; set;}
    public string PorpC {get; set;} 
}
```

I want to create a relation of one A to many Bs with the problem of having different names in the composite Principal Key:

While property PropB in class A corresponds to PropB in class B, PropA in class A has to correspond with PropC in class B.

I have tried with the model builder but I can't find a place to map the names of class A to class B:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<A>(a=>
{
    a.HasKey(a => a.Id);
    a.HasMany(a=> a.Bs).WithOne().HasPrincipalKey("PropA", "PropB"); <= Can't find PropA in classB
});
```

How can I do that?

**Note**: I can't modify the database and creating the relationship with the Id atribute is not an option.

Comment: You should be able to use `modelBuilder.Entity<A>().HasMany(x => x.Bs).WithRequired(b => b.A).HasForeignKey(b => new { b.PropA, PropB = b.PropC });`

Comment: I noticed your question mentions EF6 but the syntax looks like EF Core... can you confirm what ORM you are using?

Comment: @MateusZampol I can't use HasForeignKey becuase PorpB and PropC in class B are not part of the primary key. To my understanding i need to use HasPrincipalKey to define an alternate way of connecting the two entities. Regarding to EF6 I may be confused, I'm rather new to .Net. I see Microsoft.NETCore.App marked as a Framework dependency in the project but i also see Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory version 6 as a Package. Is this EF Core then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure! Add a `.HasForeignKey` call (and preferentially use the lambda versions of the fluent configuration methods).

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<A>(a =>
{
    a.HasKey(a => a.Id);
    a.HasMany(a => a.Bs).WithOne()
        .HasPrincipalKey(a => new { a.PropA, a.PropB })
        .HasForeignKey(b => new { b.PropC, b.PropB });
});
```

And the resulting table definitions:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [A] (
  [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
  [PropA] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
  [PropB] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_A] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
  CONSTRAINT [AK_A_PropA_PropB] UNIQUE ([PropA], [PropB])
);
CREATE TABLE [B] (
  [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
  [PropB] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
  [PropC] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_B] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
  CONSTRAINT [FK_B_A_PropC_PropB] FOREIGN KEY ([PropC], [PropB])
      REFERENCES [A] ([PropA], [PropB]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Note that the reference to `PropA` and `PropB` in class `A` causes EF to generate a unique index over these properties, in order to make the identification succeed. (Or, when not using migrations, it makes EF assume that the combination is unique. )

In other words, for EF the two properties are an *alternate key* (hence the `AK` prefix in the index). This also means that, just as primary key properties, you won't be able to modify these properties using EF, so this is a design decision that requires careful consideration.